# SQL - Nearest record within the same group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to allocate records of type y a parent id.  If there is a record of type x which has the same location, or the location is within 5 less than the type y record, and it is within the same group then I need to allocate that records id as the parent ID.  There could be multiple x records which meet this condition so I need to take the nearest.

To be clear I can only set the parentid if the type is Y and the target is type x.  Type X's can not have a parentid.

Hopefully these before and after tables will demonstrate what I am trying to do.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

I was going to do this in code but hopefully it should be possible to do this in SQL.  I am using SQL server if that affects the answer?

Greatly appreciate any help.

Cheers

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set ParentId = (select top 1 id
                    from table t2
                    where t2."type" = 'x' and
                          t2."group" = t."group"
                          t2.location between t.location - 5 and t.location
                    order by location
                   )
    from table t
    where "type" = 'y';
```